# ILNumerics V5: 3d plot gets distorted when rotate or pan

Tags: plot, scaling, ilnumerics

I have an problem: My 3d plot gets distorted, if I rotate or pan the plot. I know this behaviour is intended to show the user the most at all times, but it looks silly, so I want an orthogonal view or Axes which are equally long.

[Earth distorted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJwO8.jpg)

I have an WPF Application, where the ILN Form/Control is hosted via WindowsFormsHost.
I tried every possibility regarding Plotcube.Projection, have set Plotcube.Limits, changed ILN_Panel autosize etc. My next idea was that maybe I need to configure the WPF and/or Forms window itself.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible. At least not easy within PlotCube. If you do not need PlotCube just put the object into the Camera node and set Projection to Orthogonal. And you are done.

With PlotCube it is much more complicated. You must make sure that all containers have equal aspect ratio (width / height) WinformsHostControl, PlotCube, PlotCube.ScreenRect, PlotCube.DataScreenRect, PlotCube.Plots (data group), and its Limits. If you want to rotate everything free you must make sure to have equal aspect ration on all 3 dimensions wehere applicable.

Comment: Thanks that clears things. I would then do it without plotcube. If I need Axes, I would add them to Camera node too?